# Styling bullets and numbers in <ul> and <ol>

Tags: html, css

How can I get access to the actual bullet and/or number in CSS selectors for `<ul>` and `<ol>`? I'd specifically like to increase the `font-size` and `font-weight` of the numbers/bullets to make my items stand out more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't select them specifically, but you can style the `li` and wrap the `li`'s contents with a `span` (or whatever) and style that differently.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zTjQe/).

Answer (score 0):

Use display-block whenever you are styling inline elements.(e.g: `<a>, <span>`...)Its a minor thing to remember but usually people forgot it.